# How to add additional tags to an existing PGN?

Tags: software, pgn

Is there any software that would allow me to add additional PGN tags to existing PGN files?

For example, PGN tags like `WhiteTeam` etc.

Comment: It would be nice if your question title had some sort of indication of what the question was.  "need your help with this request" doesn't give anyone a clue as to whether they can answer it (or whether they might have the same question!) unless they click and read the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

PGN files are flat text files.  You can simply edit them with a text editor.  (I use Notepad++).

Comment: thank you yes but were talking of a pgn with over 1000 games and having to determin which player is in which team is huge work...

Comment: For simplicity sake, It doesn't matter, if all you're trying to do is fix the PGN.  The size of the text file means only that your editor must be able to handle large files.  That said you can 'modify games' in PGN form using a study tool called SCID (there's a separate program just like SCID called SCIDvsPC, both available at sourceforge for free).

Comment: thank you very much, just realised that some tourney organiser does not mention the players team in their pgn which messes up my ranking table as the script is looking for team names

Comment: The program SCID also comes with the ability to modify information about the game using a config file.  For example SCID can replace "Fisher" with "Robert Fisher" everywhere it appears in your database of games.